# Programatically redirecting user with windows authentication

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, iis, ntlm

I have a web application that users windows authentication NTLM, my app will check if password has expired and forces users to reset password or just passes user straight through if password is ok.

So doing the password check is ok I just need to know how to redirect WITHOUT re-authenticating, is this possible programmatically. I have read it seems to be easy enough using basic auth but wondering if it can be done on windows auth.

So basically I need to redirect a user to windows auth website with a set of credentials I have programmatically specified so the user gets no additional logins.....Is that possible and if so point me in the right direction!

Thanks

Comment: If you use windows authentication and the password is expired, won't the account be blocked (and therefore unable to authenticate)?

Comment: yes! My plan: Login page captures credentials, website checks ad makes them change password if password expired (done). Then I want to pass them through with there new credentials and authenticate to a windows auth website.